# package file from packagerefernce

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, yaml, appveyor

We are using appveyor as CI CD tool to build and deploy our website. Currently in my yaml file i have following code

```
- 7z a MyTest.zip .\MyProj\MyProj.Test\bin\*  .\MyProj\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0\tools\*
```

This used to work fine. We changed project structure in visual studio to use new 2017 SDK .net core style. Now packages folder is not available and it now uses packagereference.

So now it complains on this line in yaml  saying specified path not found

```
.\MyProj\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.9.0\tools\*
```

So now how can i package this file?

Answer (score 0):

Packages installed via `PackageReference` will now be found at `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` instead of within the project directory, so change your 7z call accordingly.